# Junit - Testsuite - Classnames from file

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a junit test suite as below and it works as expected.

```
  @RunWith(Suite.class)
  @Suite.SuiteClasses({
          abc.class,
          xyz.class 
   })
   public class RunSuiteIT {}
```

Now my requirement is to keep the class names (abc,xyz) in a json file and get it read during run time. Is it possible to do that in Java/JUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this at runtime, which means you can't use an annotation. Instead you will need a `static Suite suite()` method that reads the JSON file and uses the reflection API to create the `Class` instances from the string input.